# Check beforehand if will pass emissions test?

Tags: obd-ii, bluetooth, electronic-control-module, elm-327, emissions

How can I check, using an Bluetooth ELM327 OBD-II dongle, whether my car will pass an emissions test?

Answer (score 2):

Use a free app like [AndrOBD](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.fr3ts0n.ecu.gui.androbd/) or Torque Lite; here's a screenshot from the latter, the top widget of which is that of a car that passes emissions testing:

[image: Torque Lite Emissions Readiness screenshot]